# To Open the application from the widget when the app is paused

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to open the app activity by executing onCreate function every time from the widget, even when the app is paused.

Below code is from  widget configuration activity:

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget,R.drawable.feed_detail_share);
            Intent defineIntent = new Intent(ConfigurationActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
            defineIntent.putExtra("from_widget",true);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(ConfigurationActivity.this,0 /* no requestCode */, defineIntent, 0 /* no flags */);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_widget, pendingIntent1);
```

This is my app's activity which is executed on widget's onClick:

```
 Intent intent =getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("from_widget")) {
        boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("from_widget", false);
        Log.e("tag", "==========flag fromm the widget==============" + flag);
    }else{
        Log.e("tag","=========no flag from tag======");
    }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This could be solved posting your code and error log

Comment: grammatical errors

Answer (score 0):

Do like This hope it will work for you

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle !=null){
        boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("from_widget", false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

myself found a solution.

```
Intent defineIntent = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
    defineIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

In EditActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);     
    if(intent.hasExtra("from_widget")) {           

    }else{

    }
}
```